# Creating and annotating simple geographical maps in Django

Tags: django, maps, gis

I am looking for a simple way to create geographical maps in Django, in which I could then select, highlight and annotate countries or groups thereof.

"Annotate": insert a label displaying textual information about the said country.

Is there anything that comes to mind?

Many thanks

EDIT: I checked GeoDjango already and it looks like much work in order to get where I need to. Don't get me wrong: I'm not trying to minimize my own investment in learning new tools, but for this project, I have a trade-off between time allocated to learning and the relative importance of this geographical feature in my app. It's more of a nice-to-have feature I'd like to add to an already 'complete' app. So I wondered whether there exists a 'simpler' python library for this task.

Comment: Not sure your requirements.. but GeoDjango could be helpful
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've already checked GeoDjango: edited the post in order to clarify a bit my requirements.

Comment: Its hard without requirements, do you need something like google maps? Or more like an SVG map? Regardless this will definitely require some front-end javascript

Comment: Ideally, I'd need some method that could create a map object (SVG looks right), on which I could slap some label. The country and the label could be selected through a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of a question for if there is a front-end library to elegantly handle this. However if you need to generate the maps you could try something like this

https://kartograph.org/

I have personally used this http://jvectormap.com/ and found it to be really good.

In your database you could just have a Countries model with any associated information you might need to display, and create a view to handle that appropriately.

Comment: Both look good! I'll try and apply these tools. I happen to already have the Country model. Many thanks for your help!